# Import functions from several files in one import statement

Tags: python, module, python-import

After studying the docs I cannot find the answer to this.
I have a directory structure:

```
views/
  __init__py
  view1.py
  view2.py
```

In view1 and view2 are my view-functions. What do I have to do to be able to import all view functions from view1.py and view2.py with one single import:

```
import views
```

Comment: `from views import *`  ?

Comment: I thought "import views" and "from views import *" is the same?

Comment: @caliph: no, they are not. `import views` binds the name `views` to the module object. `from views import *` takes all attributes of the `views` module and creates separate names for them in the current namespace.

Comment: @caliph: See the [Python tutorial on importing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: The first question is: Why do you want to do this? If you always want anyone to have access to everything in `view1` and `view2` via `views`, you may want to just change `views` to forward everything—e.g., go into `views/__init__.py` and add `from view1 import *` then `from view2 import *`.

Comment: @abanert: Yes, that what I want to do. But `from view1 import *` in `__init__.py` results in `No module named view1`

Answer (score 0):

```
from views import view1, view2
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing all comments and verifying below is the answer.

- If `__init__.py` is declared with below line

  `__all__ = ["view1", "view2"]` then

  **Solution** : `from views import *`
- Else If `__init__.py` is not defined with `__all__` line or missing view1 , view2 in the list then

  **Solution** : `from views import view1, view2`

In the code file where you do the import do access the functions as below

```
view1.view1()
view2.view2()
```

> Reference : [modules-packages documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)